# pointer size and range of address it can hold

Tags: c

A pointer will be allocated 1 byte , so it can address upto 2^8 addresses ,i.e only 128 address , but a 32-bit machine can address upto 2^32 addresses , then how will the pointer hold an address of more than 8-bit , i am very confused can anyone please help.

Comment: What does the first sentence mean -- is that an assertion, an assumption, an assessment or a question? Whichever way, it makes little sense.

Comment: On a 32-bit machine, the pointer is usually 4 bytes.

Comment: on 32bit machine the pointer would be 32bit(4 bytes)

Comment: You sound like you're confusing the size of data a 1-byte allocation can hold vs. the addressable limits of a pointer in-general. To that, all I can say is, study more.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's why we should be extremely careful when saying silly things like "you must allocate this pointer and free that pointer" in the face of innocent minds. The correct language is more verbose, but see what the incorrect one has got us :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB The very reason I refer to "the address held in pointer <blah>" and not just "pointer <blah>", though it still doesn't seem to gel with most of those minds.

Comment: @yu Hoa but a character pointer is 1 byte right

Comment: @user2717079 That's unlikely. Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char *));` and see the result. I think you misunderstood the concept, maybe you mean the size of `char`.

Comment: @user2717079 *no*. A pointer is a variable that holds an address. What that address *addresses* (redundancy intended) is another matter. This is fundamental to C/C++ and you need to spend some time learning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a pointer for a 32 bit binary  will generally be 4 bytes. If you compile your code as a 64 bit binary, the size of the pointer should be 8 bytes. It is sufficently large to address the available memory.

You can check the size of a pointer variable of any type like this

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int *));
```

It seems like you are confused between the size of `char` and `char *`. `char` stores a character variable and its size is one byte. You can check it:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char));
```

However, `char *` is a pointer to a `char` and its size will generally be 4 bytes in a 32 bit environment

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: the size of char *p will be one byte , can u please explain this

Comment: The size of a `char` is one byte. However, the size of a `char *` will be 4 bytes assuming you are working with a 32 bit system.

Comment: @user2717079 you are confusing the size of 'char' with 'char*'.
Size of 'char*' is completely depend on your machine arch.

Comment: @kunal use "%ld" ,since sizeof return long integer.

Comment: @AmirNaghizadeh Wrong, `sizeof` returns `size_t`, which is very properly printed by `%zu` just like it says.